# why do I still receive insufficient permission error despite giving full mail scope?

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

```
import httplib2
import os
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client, tools
from apiclient import errors, discovery

SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'

APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python List Email'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret_ishandutta2007.json'# This file will be in local dir
CREDENTIAL_FILE_NAME = 'gmail-python-email-send_ishandutta2007.json'

def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, CREDENTIAL_FILE_NAME)
    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        print(('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path))
    return credentials


def ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, user_id, query=''):
    try:
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query).execute()
        messages = []
        if 'messages' in response:
            messages.extend(response['messages'])

        while 'nextPageToken' in response:
            page_token = response['nextPageToken']
            response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query,
                                                pageToken=page_token).execute()
            messages.extend(response['messages'])

        return messages
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)

def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, "me", query="senior recruit")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> An error occurred: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=senior+recruit&alt=json
>   returned "Insufficient Permission">

Answer (score 1):

Found the issues,in the code above it was picking up a cached credentials from the file `gmail-python-email-send_ishandutta2007.json` which has permission to send mails only, changing this filename to something new fixed the issue.